# Lookup finding the same name through different bases in multiple inheritance with identical values

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance, name-lookup

Say I have a class that inherits from two different classes. They both have an alias like `using type_alias = int;`. Should looking up `type_alias` in the scope of the class be `int` or ambiguous? What if both of the different classes inherited that type alias from the same class?

Here are some other examples:

```cpp
enum enum_type {
    enumerator
};

template<int>
struct base {
    using type_alias = int;
    using enum enum_type;
};

struct derived : base<0>, base<1> {};

derived::type_alias main() {
    return derived::enumerator;
}

derived::base<2> x;  // injected-class-name
```

```cpp
template<int>
struct super_base_template {};

struct super_base : super_base_template<0> {
    using type_alias = int;
    enum enum_type {
        enumerator
    };
    static constexpr int static_member = 2;
};


template<int>
struct base : super_base {};

struct derived : base<0>, base<1> {};

derived::type_alias main() {
    return derived::enumerator;
}

derived::super_base_template<derived::static_member> x;
```

clang seems to be able to compile all of this, whereas gcc only likes it if they are inherited from literally the same declaration, like in the second snippet and the last line of the first snippet.

Which of these are valid lookups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[class.member.lookup]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup) describes how a search for a name in the scope of a class is performed. The part relevant to this question is p5.2:

> - Otherwise, if the declaration sets of *S(N, B<sub>i</sub>)* and *S(N,C)* differ, the merge is ambiguous...

The wording makes no exception for different declarations denoting the same entity; the lookup is ambiguous even if both found declarations are `using type_alias = int;`. Conversely, if there is only one declaration (originating from the same base class), that declaration is the unambiguous result of the lookup:

```cpp
struct A { using X = int; };
struct B : A { using Y = int; };
struct C : A { using Y = int; };
struct D : B, C {};
D::X x; // OK
D::Y y; // ambiguous
```

---

Regarding the specific examples: in the first snippet,

- `derived::type_alias` is ambiguous as described above,
- `derived::enumerator` unambiguously refers to the declaration of `enumerator` on the second line: `using enum enum_type;` is equivalent to `using enum_type::enumerator;` ([[enum.udecl]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/enum.udecl#2.sentence-1)), and *using-declarator*s are replaced during lookup by the declarations they name ([[basic.lookup.general]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#3.sentence-2)),
- `derived::base` unambiguously refers to the class template `base` per [[temp.local]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#4).

There's a single declaration to be found for every lookup in `derived::` in the second snippet, so there's no ambiguity there.

Comment: What about this sentence: [In the declaration set, type declarations (including injected-class-names) are replaced by the types they designate.](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#2.sentence-2) It looks like S("type_alias", `base<0>`) is { `int` } (instead of containing "the alias declaration in `base<0>`, distinct from the one in `base<1>`") and so is S("type_alias", `base<1>`), so it shouldn't be ambiguous?

Comment: That sentence was added to resolve [CWG306](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/306.html). Under a literal interpretation, I don't think it applies in this case: strictly speaking, a typedef declaration does not declare a type (only a *typedef-name*), and I don't see how the type `int` itself can be part of a *declaration* set. But whether that is the intended interpretation, I'm not entirely sure. The standard is in general not consistent on this, see e.g. [\[basic.lookup.general\]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#4.sentence-4).